# Thermodynamic factor of a ternary system

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to calculate the thermodynamic factor of a ternary system, based on its Gibbs energy, but I'm struggling.
Based on the book "Multicomponent mass transfer" by R. Taylor & R. Krishna, I know that the thermodynamic factor $\Gamma$ of a multi-component system is given as a (N - 1)x(N-1) matrix, where n is the number of components. So for a ternary system, I want a 2x2 matrix, where the elements are given as (again from Taylor & Krishna):

$$
\Gamma_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + x_i \left( Q_{ij} - Q_{in} - \sum_{k = 1}^N x_k \left( Q_{kj} - Q_{kn}\right) \right) ,
$$

$Q = \frac{G_\mathrm{E}}{R T}$, i.e., the excess Gibbs energy over the typical $ RT$ terms, and they have defined the derivatives $Q_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$, where $x_i$ is the mole fraction of component $i$. $\delta_{ij}$ is the kronecker-delta.

That's OK in theory, but that means that I for e.g. $\Gamma_{11}$, I need to evaluate

$$
\Gamma_{11} = 1 + x_1 \left( Q_{11} - Q_{13} - \sum_{k = 1}^3 x_k \left( Q_{k1} - Q_{1n}\right) \right) ,
$$

with the derivative of $Q$ wrt. $x_3$. But due to being a 3-component system, the 3rd component is given by $x_3 = 1 - x_1 - x_2$. How do I calculate this third derivative?

For the function of $G$, and thus $Q$, I have a ternary Redlich-Kister-type function dependent on $x_1$ and $x_2$, and temperature $T$.

For the derivative, I use the finite difference method, so I expect the double-derivative wrt. $x_1$ to be,

$$
\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x_1^2} \approx \frac{Q(x_1 + \Delta x, x_2) - 2 Q(x_1, x_2) + Q(x_1 - \Delta x, x_2)}{(\Delta x)^2} ,
$$
and so on for the other derivatives, with a small $\Delta x$.